# The benefits of hemorrhage on a subtlety rogue

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Having recently reupped my World of Warcraft subscription after a long hiatus, I have decided to start fresh on a dwarf rogue and am currently level 43. I decided to try out subtlety but am slightly confused by the ability [Hemorrhage](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=16511). The ability says

```
...causes the target to take 30% additional damage from Bleed effects for 1 min.
```

However I'm having trouble seeing what rogue abilities cause a bleeding effect. The only one I can see is [Garrote](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=703) and that's an opening move. After that, in an extended fight, I don't see much point to using hemo. Am I missing something? Is there a point to using hemo after the garrote wears off of an enemy?

Comment: I had to blink for a moment when I saw the phrase "The benefits of hemorrhage" on my screen.

Comment: @Grace XD Yeah not something you'd see every day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there's a few benefits to using Hemorrhage.

First off, it boosts the damage of your bleed effect -  specifically, of Rupture and Garrote. Mainly Rupture is the important one here, because it's not an opener, and because, in fact, it's the highest damage/energy finisher you have available. Especially because, thanks to [Sanguinary Vein](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=79147/sanguinary-vein), you'll always want to have a bleed effect up on your target in order to do more damage with all of your other abilities.

Thing is, the debuff from Hemo doesn't just increase the damage from *your* bleeds. It increases the damage of bleed effects applied by everyone else in the raid. That means Marksmanship Hunters, Warriors, other Rogues, and especially Feral Druids all will do a lot more damage in groups with you if you keep the Hemo debuff up. Hemorrhage is the Subtlety Rogues contribution to 'raid utility'.

Lastly, and most importantly for solo play, 5 mans, and leveling, is that with the [Glyph of Hemorrhage](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42967/glyph-of-hemorrhage), you can actually use Hemo to apply the bleed necessary to keep Sanguinary Vein active without worrying about using Rupture. This means that by using Hemo as your first unstealthed attack, the damage of *all of your other abilities*, including auto-attacks and poisons, goes up by 10% for 24 seconds -  enough time to kill a short lived mob, and enough time to get a Rupture up on a boss that will live long enough for it to tick out.

Answer (score 2):

[Bleed effects](http://www.wowpedia.org/Bleed) are a type of DoT. So, this is a a way to increase the effectiveness of your bleed inducing abilities ([Garrote](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=703) and [Rupture](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=1943)). Bleed effects can't be dispelled except by ice block, pally bubbles, and the dwarf racial "Stoneform". There was [a trinket](http://www.wowhead.com/item=19141), but it didn't work past level 60 and has since been removed from the game.

Comment: Ah I missed rupture apparently. Makes more sense to use once I get that.

Comment: @the jug: Dots are huge against fast moving squishy targets.

Comment: Ah, the days of being a dwarf paladin against Moroes in Karazhan...

Comment: @Raven Dreamer Yeah, I <3 dwarves a lot. Was a dwarf hunter during that time and it always amused me to hear everyone freaking out over someone getting garroted from Moroes. I calmly hovered over my stoneform button told the healers to stay calm and went back to dpsing.